# I met the 'xmemory' file when I delete my memory alloced array in C++

Tags: c++

I have a problem about my code.

```
#include "Media.h"
#include "DVD.h"
#include "LegalDVD.h"
#include "VTR.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
// 주석점수 10점
// 보고서 점수 20점
// static int count값을 0으로 초기화 (10점)
int Media::count = 0;

int main(void)
{
    Media* mp[4];
    // new 할때마다 count증가하도록 구현 (10점)
    mp[0] = new VTR("Hello", 15, "avi");
    mp[1] = new DVD("Superman", 3, "123-9899");
    mp[2] = new LegalDVD("Marvel", 10, "456-9899", "GG entertainment");
    mp[3] = new VTR("Disney", 23, "mkv");

    for (int i = 0; i < Media::count; i++) // 다형성 구현 (20점)
        mp[i]->play();
    cout << "연산자 오버로딩 실습" << endl;
    cout << mp[0]; // "VTR이 play되고 있습니다."가 출력되도록 연산자 5오버로딩 구현(30점)
    mp[3] = *mp[1] + mp[2]; //“mp[1]의 length+mp[2]의 length”가 되게끔 오버로딩 (30점)
    cout << mp[3]->getLength() << endl; // 출력값은 13

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        delete mp[i]; **//ERORR!!!**


    return 0; // new한 객체들이 잘 소멸되는지 보일 것 (20점)
}
```

If I run the code, the 'xmemory' file apears and showed a error message 'Exception thrown: read access violation.
_Pnext was 0xDDDDDDE1.'

How can I fix it? ;(

+

Here is my operator overloading about +, = in Media.cpp
[image]

Comment: Please don't spam multiple different languages, when it is clearly nothing to do with them.

Comment: Somewhere you are writing outside the bounds of an allocated object. The problem is likely in `mp[3] = *mp[1] + mp[2];`. [Edit] the question to include a [mre] that allows us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: After `mp[3] = *mp[1] + mp[2]`, the value in `mp[3]` is not the value that was returned by the earlier `new`. If the code deletes that pointer, the behavior of the program is undefined. To fix it, don't do that. <g>